# Create a shared folder between Mac(Host) and Ubuntu(GUEST) on virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine, shared-folders

On my Mac I have virtualbox installed with Ubuntu.

When I go into the settings of the virtual machine, under the section that allows you to create a Shared folder I select the folder I want to be shared (the folder is on the desktop of the mac), but then nothing appens in Ubuntu.

I can't find the mentioned folder and if I restart the VM and go check the Shared Folder's Options all the previous settings are gone as if I've never set any folder to be shared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved. You have to add some priviledges to your user:

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxsf
```

then you'll find the folder under `/media`.
The name will be sf_NAME.
When editing the settings for Shared Folder **check** the **Auto Mount** box.

`$USER` Will automatically expand to your full username